# Python, csv.writer made an empty list every iteration

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

So i have this 2d array

```
z = [["test","dus"],["dus","ta"]]
```

then i want to write it to an csv files by using this python code:

```
with open('test.csv','w') as out:
csv_out=csv.writer(out)
csv_out.writerow(['input','output'])
for row in z:
    csv_out.writerow(row)
```

it successfully written it in the csv however i don't get why the results look like this:

```
input output

test dus

dus ta
```

so it create an empty list after each iteration which doesn't make sense why is this happening ? is it possible to avoid it ?

Comment: Common problem on windows, fix with `with open('test.csv','w', newline='') as out:`

Comment: Seed documentation of `csv.writer()` https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @Primusa Thanks man that fixed it